# Why with base index 1 C program works fine?

Tags: c, arrays

This may be a naive question but as per my understanding I know that by deafult base index of an array starts with zero.
What I don't understand is that why the following program working fine when used base 1 indexing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    printf("%d",a[n]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are just lucky

Comment: Like most C programs, it works by accident! Type `0` as the first number to see uninitialized memory.

Comment: [Undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: the code will compile but with compiler warning because of exceeds the array limit ..

Comment: @vaibhav compilers do not need to warn for this

Comment: @M.M I admire your comment :), then what happens in this situation with specific compiler ..?

Comment: @vaibhav try it and see

Comment: If `n` is e.g. odd, the compiler/run time will allign the memory that could still hold one additional element. So the array element is there 'by accident'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that why the following program working fine

it's just bad luck.

This is undefined behaviour. That means the compiler doesn't have to warn you, and no code is emitted to check it at runtime.

Undefined means completely undefined, which includes *working*, and *appearing to work until after you ship it to a customer*, as well as the more obvious *locking up your machine, formatting all the disks and setting fire to your PSU*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will compile but you won't get expected results.
First element of array `a` will not be printed and one garbage value will be printed at end of array as there is no bound checking for arrays in c.

Comment: The code shouldn't compile. `int a[n]` is not allowed. In C++ you could do `int *a = new int[n]` but not in C.

Comment: Variable-length arrays were added in C99 iirc.

Comment: @GraemePerrow it's the 21st century now

Comment: @M.M Doesn't compile with VC 12.0. "Error: expected constant expression"

Comment: @GraemePerrow Variable Length Arrays allows `int a[n]`, is a C feature introduced in C99 and optionally available with C11 (the latest in 2016).  I have doubts that VC 12.0 is that compliant with either of those standards in regards to VLA.

Comment: MS haven't updated their C compiler's compliance since the 1980s